# Dynamic regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, match, split

Trying to make an expression dynamic. So I can split a string up in equal chunks.

`var keyParts = key.match(/.{1,4}/g);`

`var keyParts = key.match(/.{rangeA,rangeB}/g);`

So I want to make a range, I was trying to put it in a new RegExp() but w/o any positive results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var re = new RegExp(".{" + rangeA + "," + rangeB + "}", "g");
var keyParts = key.match(re);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bzKAq/

In the demo, notice how when you change the length of `key` to be between the ranges, it will match the string.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp